# Solving a limit of integral with L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have this limit:
$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^x \dfrac{1}{2+\cos(\mathrm t)}\, \mathrm{dt}$

I said that

Edit:
$-1\leq \cos\mathrm{t}\leq 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2+\cos\mathrm{t}} > 0 \text{ and because that expression has no limit as x -> inf}\\\Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_{0}^x \dfrac{1}{2+\cos\mathrm{t}}\, dt \to \infty \\ \\ \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^x \dfrac{1}{2+\cos\mathrm{t}}\,\mathrm{dt}}{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\Big( \displaystyle\int_{0}^x \dfrac{1}{2+\cos \mathrm{t}}\, \mathrm{dt}\Big)'}{x'} = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2+\cos \mathrm{x}}}{1} = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{2+\cos \mathrm{x}}$

But here I got stuck because that limit does not exist, because cos x has no limit when x goes to infinity.

But the correct answer is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong (yet), you just got stuck ;) L'Hôpital's rule is not applicable here. Use $2\pi$-periodicity of the integrand to see that the limit is equal to the expression obtained by setting $x=2\pi$.

Comment: $f(t)>0$ does not imply $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt=\infty$. For example, take $f(t)=e^{-t}$.

Comment: @MathIsFun

Yes, But because 2/(1+cost) does not have limit as x -> inf or x -> -inf it means the integral -> inf.

Comment: The integral is indeed not convergent at $\infty$, because $\frac{1}{2+\cos t}\ge\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @metamorphy
You are right.
Replacing x with 2pi the limit goes 1/sqrt(3).

Comment: Your problem is that L'Hopital's rule does not apply. Specifically, L'Hopital says $\lim f/g = \lim f'/g'$ **if** $\lim f'/g'$ exists, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Quang Hoang
I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\int^{2\pi n}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t} = n \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi n}\int^{2\pi n}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi }_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}.
\end{align}

Hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi n}\int^{2\pi n}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi }_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.
\end{align}

This suggests that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int^x_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
if the limit exists.

To show that the limit exists, observe we have that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{x}\int^{x}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}\right| =&\ \left|\frac{1}{2\pi n+r}\int^{2\pi n+r}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}\right|\\
=&\ \left|\frac{n}{2\pi n+r}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\right|\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{dt}{2+\cos t}+ \frac{1}{2\pi n+r}\int^{r}_{0} \frac{dt}{2+\cos t}
\end{align}
where $0\le r< 2\pi$. Then as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you!
Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $\cos x$ is periodic of period $2\pi$ (as per a comment).

Thus, we are just getting the average area over an interval of length $2\pi$.

Using Wolfram alpha, say, we get $\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac 1{2+\cos x}\operatorname dx=\dfrac {2\pi}{\sqrt3}$.